# html5 article or section

Tags: html, tags, article

I am making an "About" section on a webpage in HTML5 and I am not quite sure whether to use the `<article>` or `<section>` tag. It is just a page containing some about info. The `<article>` tag seems more logic to me, but I am not sure

```
<h1>ABOUT</h1>
<div class="white-box">
    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum ultricies nisi nec commodo. Sed condimentum dapibus scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam ut ornare lorem. Duis porttitor sagittis accumsan. Morbi non eros augue, quis pellentesque purus. Cras id purus nec nunc ullamcorper fringilla sit amet lobortis quam.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A section tag tag defines sections in a document. Such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document.

The  tag specifies independent, self-contained content.
An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to distribute it independently from the rest of the site.

Potential sources for the  element:

- Forum post
- Blog post
- News story

Now it depends on how you want to display your about us section.

Comment: Thanks for putting it this way :) It might make more sense to make it as a section markup-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an aside tag since information about an article is related to the main topic of the web page, but is not its primary concern.